# ReferenceError: array is not defined getRange().setvalues()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to set the values in a certain column and for some reason that i cant figure out Its says that my array isn't defined.

```
function myFunction() {
  var Date1 = new Date(); // Today's date
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arr = Sheet.getRange("AB2:AB6").getValues(); // Recruitment Dates
  var Rowlimit = arr.length;
  var DaysArr = [new Array()];
  for(i = 0 ; i< Rowlimit; i++)
  {
    var TodayTime = Date1.getTime();
    var RecDayTime =  (new Date(arr[i][0])).getTime(); //converting from string to Date Type, and converting to the miliseconds number.
    var DaysBetween = Math.abs(Math.floor((TodayTime-RecDayTime)/(24*3600*1000))); // Getting the difference in miliseconds and converting the miliseconds to days
    Logger.log(DaysBetween);
    DaysArr[0].push(DaysBetween);
  }
  Logger.log(DaysArr);
  
Logger.log(DaysArr[0]);
Sheet.getRange("AA2:AA6").setValues(Daysarr);
}
```

below is the execution log, sorry for the wierd language, its just that the drive is set on hebrew

```
11:03:34    הודעה   ההפעלה התחילה
11:03:33    מידע    95.0
11:03:33    מידע    529.0
11:03:33    מידע    382.0
11:03:33    מידע    200.0
11:03:33    מידע    180.0
11:03:33    מידע    [[95.0, 529.0, 382.0, 200.0, 180.0]]
11:03:33    מידע    [95.0, 529.0, 382.0, 200.0, 180.0]
11:05:25    שגיאה   ReferenceError: Daysarr is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `DaysArr` is declared. But at `Sheet.getRange("AA2:AA6").setValues(Daysarr);`, `Daysarr` is used. I thought that the reason of your error message is due to this.
- As another modification point, from your script, `Logger.log(DaysArr[0]);` is `[95.0, 529.0, 382.0, 200.0, 180.0]`. But in your script, `Sheet.getRange("AA2:AA6").setValues(Daysarr);`. In this case, I think that it is required to transpose the value.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
Sheet.getRange("AA2:AA6").setValues(Daysarr);
```

#### To:

```
Sheet.getRange("AA2:AA6").setValues(DaysArr[0].map(e => [e]));
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)